# How to remove/replace ASCII code backspace

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I need help to remove BS (backspace ) ASCII code from a textarea.

```
<cfoutput>
<textarea id="texarea">
#replace(replace(replace(getHistoryDet.results,"[BS","","ALL"),"#</textarea><br/>
</cfoutput>
```

Any ideas how to remove this character? What do you suggest?

Comment: Remove the BS one at a time.

<cfoutput>
<textarea id="texarea">
#replace(replace(replace(getHistoryDet.results,"BS","","ALL"),"#</textarea><br/>
#replace(replace(replace(getHistoryDet.results,"chr(08)","","ALL"),"#</textarea><br/>
</cfoutput>

Comment: thx @Vlad why you have </textarea twice? 
thank you for your support

Comment: i tried your theory but i have still the BS ASCII code visible i can't not remove it

Comment: Hi @claudio I've tidy it up. Maybe you are also having the problem with textarea gotcha. You need to have textarea in just 1 line.
<cfoutput>
 <cfset varResult = replace(getHistoryDet.results,"BS","","ALL") >
 <cfset varResult = replace(getHistoryDet.results,"chr(08)","","ALL") >
 <textarea id="texarea">#varResult#</textarea><br/>  
</cfoutput>

Comment: like this
<textarea id="texarea">#varResult#</textarea>